# The program is not able to show the output from second iteration onwards

Tags: c++

```
for(int i=0;i<T;i++)   // t test cases
{
    int flag=0;        //flag variable to check the output
    char A[3][3];

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)        //Taking
        for(int k=0;k<3;k++)     //Input
           cin>>A[j][k];          //in a character Array

    //checking for letter 'l' in the character array and if other l's  also exist or not

    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
      for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        if(A[j][k]=='l')
        {
            if(A[j+1][k]=='l' && A[j+1][k+1]=='l')
                flag++;
        }
    }

     if(flag>0)
            cout<<"yes"<<endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

This is my code, the problem was to check if in a 3*3 character array, if there is a pattern like 
l
ll

It works for the 1st iteration correctly or for the 1st test case but it's showing no result from 2nd onwards.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't work? I just copied and pasted it and seems to work just fine for me. You can test it on: https://onlinegdb.com/r1VCS-FxN

Comment: Yes, I figured out what's wrong thank you!! I forgot to write else part.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly, as you can see here: onlinegdb.com/r1VCS-FxN.

You are not seeing the result when it fails because you don't have a "no" cout.

The code in the link, just in case it stops working:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int T = 3;
    cout << "T: " << T << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)   // t test cases
    {
        int flag=0;        //flag variable to check the output
        char A[3][3];

        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)        //Taking
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)     //Input
                cin>>A[j][k];          //in a character Array

        //checking for letter 'l' in the character array and if other l's  also exist or not

        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++) {
                if(A[j][k]=='l') {
                    if(A[j+1][k]=='l' && A[j+1][k+1]=='l')
                        flag++;
                }
            }
        cout << "Flags: " << flag << endl;

        if(flag>0)
            cout<<"yes"<<endl;
        else
            cout << "nope" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```